# "basic_string: construction from null is not valid" when running blender binary from newly built project

Tags: compile

I'm trying to compile the latest [upstream master branch], after the end(`exit 0`) of `make install`, running the blender binary (in `<build_dir>/blender` or in `/usr/bin`) results in this error

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
  what():  basic_string: construction from null is not valid
Aborted (core dumped)
```

after a few searches, I found that there might be literal zeros assigned to basic_string as nullptr, so I added the `-Wzero-as-null-pointer-constant` flag to the CXX flags, the compiler outputs a lot of warnings throughout the entire build.

I don't seem to know where to go from this.

Comment: This is most likely not the first error that happened. I would suggest you do a clean build with e.g. `make full debug`. Take a look whether the build throws warnings or errors. If it doesn't, check if you're able to run the binary. If it doesn't work you might be able to see what goes wrong with a debugger. Likeliest case is that you skipped some step from the build instructions or there is a bug in the specific commit you're trying to build. In the latter case, run `make update` and try again.

Comment: Since this Q&A site is dedicated to the use of Blender, but your question refers to an error that occurs when compiling the software, I'm afraid that this question is off-topic. Please be so kind and try the official website: https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Building_Blender